# I'm not sure why this code won't work?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some code, and I am trying to break it up in to different classes because of the way the code will eventually need to work, and I am also working with retrieving data from the internet, so I was trying to do two new things for myself and I can't figure out why this won't work, here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
public class SomeClass {

    SomeProjectClass_www Test = new SomeProjectClass_www();
    Test.GetData();
}

public class SomeProjectClass_www : IEnumerator {

    public IEnumerator GetData()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("file://C:\\Users\\generic_user\Documents\\test.txt");
        yield return url;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

The code generates a CS1519 error, in Unity3d which is what I am using. That is where the Debug.Log comes from. Sorry, I didn't provide much useful information, I really don't know much of whats going on.

Comment: First off, try using answers.unity3d.com, they can probably give you a better answer.  But from my experience, I'm guessing this is a web player, if so, you cannot access the file system that way via the `WWW` class.  EDIT: as Reed answered, yeah, the code is bad.  But I think you might have issues with your WWW call as well.

Comment: For starters, the first class has a call to a function that is just hanging out in the middle of the class definition.  It needs to be in some sort of method.  And SomeProjectCalss_www doesn't implement any of the members of the IEnumerator interface.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yeah, actually the code for the WWW part has actually worked before in a different set up, just trying to put it in it's own class messes with things, this actually isn't meant for web player and actually isn't a game other, more of what will be developed to an API and system.

So, yes I know I can't normally access the file system this way, I am accessing it this way at the moment because eventually it will be developed to access a web server, but for now I am just having it access a file on my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your `SomeClass` has logic defined *in the class*, not in a *method*:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    // This logic needs to go into a method
    void SomeMethod() 
    {
        SomeProjectClass_www Test = new SomeProjectClass_www();
       Test.GetData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel like an idiot, because I should have known this. Well, you need to mistakes to learn.